# Create new column in view based on calculated result from previous columns

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-workbench, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a view which will display an additional column based on the output of previous two columns like below

Current view:

| test_id | reported_date |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-05-07 |
| 12345 | 2022-05-07 |
| 23456 | 2022-05-07 |

New view:
I want to create a view which will have the data like below

| test_id | reported_date | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-05-07 | Y |
| 12345 | 2022-05-07 | N |
| 23456 | 2022-05-07 | Y |

A new column 'flag' will be added based on the test_id and reported date columns
conditions are as followed:

1. If duplicate test_ids are present--> get the ealiest one based on reported date and mark flag as Y
2. Mark the other duplicate as N
3. If test_id is not duplicate mark flag as Y

Note: Flag column is not present in any table.

Comment: *get the latest one based on reported date and mark flag as Y* your desired results indicate the opposite

Comment: @Stu, I want to mark Y to the one which came first from two duplicate test_ids

Comment: Ok - so that's the earliest then, not the latest?

Comment: @Stu, yeah sorry My bad

Answer (score 0):

You could utilise a correlated *exists* query:

```
Select Test_Id, reported_date,
  case when exists (
    select * from t t2 
    where t2.Test_Id = t.Test_Id 
      and t2.reported_date < t.reported_date
  ) then 'N' else 'Y' end as Flag
from t;
```